# Azure :Working with GraphRbacManagementClient and ServicePrincipalCredentials results with Insufficient privileges error

Tags: python-3.x, azure

I'm trying to run the code below and it ends up with the error :

> azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error.GraphErrorException: Insufficient
>   privileges to complete the operation.

prerequisite:

create an azure app with Microsoft Graph permissions

The code (python):

```
from azure.graphrbac import graph_rbac_management_client
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import ServicePrincipalCredentials
class TestAzureStuff(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.tenant = "**YOUR*tenant******"
        self.client = "*****YOUR*client*****"
        self.secret = "******YOUR*secret****"
        self.subscription = "*****YOUR*subscription****"

        self.credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=self.client,
                                                       secret=self.secret,
                                                       tenant=self.tenant,
                                                       resource="https://graph.windows.net")

    def remove_app(self):
        client = graph_rbac_management_client.GraphRbacManagementClient(self.credentials,
                                                                        self.tenant)

        client.users.list().next()


stuff = TestAzureStuff()
stuff.remove_app()
```

the only way it does work is when instead of the ServicePrincipalCredentials I use UserPassCredentials with my own credentials.
I also Checked maybe there are some permissions differences  between the app and my own user and looks like they have same permissions.

Do you have any clue what permission is missing?

or maybe I'm missing something else here?

Comment: Usually this would mean that correct application permissions are not assigned.. you do mention that `I also Checked maybe there are some permissions differences between the app and my own user and looks like they have same permissions.` so only thing I would add is to make sure you're looking at `application permissions` for the app registration linked to service principal and not the `delegated permissions`. I say this because in case of user `delegated permissions` will take effect, but in case of service principal/application `application permissions` will take effect